OneSignal expand/collapse notifications
I am using onesignal for notifications in a react native chat app, I want to receive all the app notifications in one group but when user expand them I want to display them in groups depending on conversation id (like whatsapp).
I tried to use android_group to pass conversation id, but in this case; notifications display in seperate groups without expanding.
